# Mobile mail clients adding spacing between images in table cells

Tags: html, css, mobile, html-email, email-client

Mobile mail clients like Gmail and Inbox display unwanted horizontal, but not vertical spacing between images in html mails as seen on the screenshot below. Web clients do not have that issue.

[Mobile Gmail/Inbox screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhIC3.png)

The html has the following structure:

```
     <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
           <tr>
              <td><img width="25" height="29" border="0" style="display: block" src="1.jpg"/></td>
              <td><img width="30" height="29" border="0" style="display: block" src="2.jpg"/></td>
              <td><img width="29" height="29" border="0" style="display: block" src="3.jpg"/></td>
              ... <!-- and so on -->
           </tr>
      </table>
```

All images have the right coresponding dimensions set and all the styles like padding, margin, etc. are reset. Adding dimensions and colspan to table cells does not fix the problem too.

Is it even possible to fix that issue?

Comment: try adding same `width` for `td`

Comment: Already tried it, doesn't work. I think the issue is with the images, not with the table cells.

Comment: ok did you try adding `width` for `table` ?

Comment: Yes, still no change.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has all necessary attributes and looks clean, so the problem is outside of this table. Please provide more information, ideally the whole HTML file with only this table. It is possible that problem is caused by the resizing that happens when pixels fall unevenly in high-DPI screen, when viewport is different and pixels get re-mapped by sub-pixel widths to fill it.

As a quick fix, what if you set the bgcolor to black, so the gaps would blend-in?

Do you have the correct viewport meta tag set in the `<head>`?

Comment: There is nothing different outside of this table. Just a few more tables with basically the same layout, with the only difference that the tables below contain only one image covering the full width of the table. Like this:
 `<table width="600"><tr><img width="600" src="img.jpg" style="display: block;"/></tr></table>`

And yes, the viewport meta tag is set. I changed the DOCTYPE too as I found out that it leaves whitespaces, but still no change.